# ASP.Net MVC3 - Pass razor markup as a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0, razor

I have a helper called `EditableArea` which provides a user with a runtime-editable `div` (via JS). EditableArea helper checks if an editable area (not related to MVC's `Area`) with the specified ID exists in the DB, if so then it renders the area's HTML, otherwise it displays the default markup specified as a parameter of the helper:

```
@Html.EditableArea(someId, "<p>Click to edit contents</p>")
```

It all works ok, but I'd like to change it so that the default markup is specified not as a string but in razor syntax, something like:

```
@using (Html.EditableArea(someId))
{
    <p>Click to edit contents</p>
}
```

Or something similar, like the way `@section`s work in MVC3.

How can I achieve that?

I can make an `IDisposable` which in its `Dispose` closes the TagBuilder, etc., but using this approach the markup will still be rendered (I can clear the rendered contents in the `Dispose()` but the code block would still run unnecessarily, which I'd like to avoid).

Is there some other way to pass a razor block to the helper, which may or may not be actually rendered?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's an example I use to render jQuery Template markup by passing in a template Id and razor-style syntax for the template itself:

```
public static MvcHtmlString jQueryTmpl(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
    string templateId, Func<object, HelperResult> template) 
{
    return MvcHtmlString.Create("<script id=\"" + templateId + 
        "\" type=\"x-jquery-tmpl\">" + template.Invoke(null) + "</script>");
}
```

and this would be called with

```
@Html.jQueryTmpl("templateId", @<text>any type of valid razor syntax here</text>)
```

Basically just use `Func<object, HelperResult>` as your parameter and `template.Invoke(null)` (with arguments if necessary) to render it.  Obviously you can skip the call to `.Invoke()` to avoid rendering the "default" markup.

Comment: It doesn't work. The `<text>...</text>` syntax inside the function call isn't being recognized (invalid expression term '<')

Comment: Great, it works now. `<text>` tags aren't needed at all (`@` is enough) unless the razor markup is in fact plain text without any tags, otherwise just `@<tag>` is enough.

Comment: That's correct about the `<text>` tags.  I tend to use them just in case I ever change what goes in my templates - future proof it if you will.

Comment: Why is it passing null to the template function? What does the parameter do?

Comment: 'IHtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'jQueryTmpl' and no accessible extension method 'jQueryTmpl' accepting a first argument of type 'IHtmlHelper<dynamic>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)       no mvc core??

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand on the accepted answer, as it took me quite a while to resolve a similar problem and this is the question which popped up. What I really need was a `@helper`, which would accept razor text, as the template should contain quite some code. I played around for a long while trying to use several versions of type `@helper item(Func<object, HelperResult> input)`, which I found on the web, with no success. Therefore I went for an approach like:

```
namespace project.MvcHtmlHelpers
{
    public static class HelperExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString RazorToMvcString(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Func<object, HelperResult> template)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(template.Invoke(null).ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
@project.MvcHtmlHelpers    
@helper item(other input, MvcHtmlString content)
    {
        <div class="item">
            ...other stuff... 
            <div class="content">
                @content
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

and use this via

```
@item(other input, @Html.RazorToMvcString(@<text>this is a test</text>))
```

Now I can use the helper template for both Razor input, but I can also drop in partial views, which is handy at some points. As I am no expert there might be better options, but it seems like a flexible approach to me.

Answer (score 3):

In case you're wondering this is how to do it in asp.net core 3.1

```html
@{
    void TemplateFunc(Func<object, IHtmlContent> template)
    {
        <div>@template(null)</div>
    }
}
```

Then in markup you can use it as

```html
<div>
@{TemplateFunc(@<div>123</div>);}
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Taking this further, it is possible to pass the markup directly to a helper, without an extension method.

```
@helper HelperWithChild(Func<object, HelperResult> renderChild)
{
    <div class="wrapper">
        @renderChild(this)
    </div>
}

@HelperWithChild(@<h1>Hello</h1>)
```

For multi-line markup `<text>` is required as well:

```
@HelperWithChild(@<text>
    @AnotherHelper()

    <h1>
        With more markup
    </h1>
</text>)

@helper AnotherHelper()
{
    <p>
        Another helper
    </p>
}
```

Though I'm not sure how `this` will play out with `Model` - my helpers only use their parameters.