# MVC3 how to use @<text></text> as html helper parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, lambda, html-helper

I'm a little lost with the creation of an MVC3 Helper. I have my helper that just create a row with an expression that is passed as parameter.

I want to use my htmlHelper like this:

```
@Html.AddTableFormField(model => model.UserName, @<text>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserName)<span class="warning">Use only letters</span>
    </text>)
```

This is my HtmlHelper (some irrelevant code was removed):

```
public static MvcHtmlString AddTableFormField<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> property, Expression<Func<TModel>> customFormat = null)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(property, htmlHelper.ViewData);

        string displayName = metadata.DisplayName;

        var propName = metadata.PropertyName;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(displayName))
            displayName = propName;

        MvcHtmlString htmlCustomFormat = null;

        if (customFormat != null)
        {
            var deleg = customFormat.Compile();
            htmlCustomFormat = new MvcHtmlString(deleg().ToString());
        }
        else
            htmlCustomFormat = htmlHelper.EditorFor(property);

        return new MvcHtmlString(string.Format("<tr>"+
                "<td class=\"form-label\">"+
                    "<label class=\"editor-label\" for=\"{0}\">{1}<label>"+
                "</td>"+
                "<td class=\"form-data\">"+
                    "{2}"+
                "</td>"+
            "</tr>",
            propName, displayName, htmlCustomFormat));
    }
```

I can't even compile it, because the *`@<text>...</text>`* parameter is invalid for the HtmlHelper because it is an 'lambda expression' and cannot be converted into Expression>

Anyone can help to solve it? I just want to pass any kind of `@<text></text>` to my HtmlHelper, and it just compile it and put it's MvcHtmlString into the formated return.

**SOLUTION:**

I found What I was looking for in this post:
[ASP.Net MVC3 - Pass razor markup as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157772/asp-net-mvc3-pass-razor-markup-as-a-parameter)

The parameter type for the `@<text></text>` must be an `Func<object, HtmlHelper>` !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found What I was looking for in this post:
[ASP.Net MVC3 - Pass razor markup as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157772/asp-net-mvc3-pass-razor-markup-as-a-parameter)

The parameter type for the `@<text></text>` must be an `Func<object, HelperResult>` !

Answer (score 2):

The `<text>...</text> or @:` is a Razor syntax (not C#) to avoid html elements, so my usggestion will be that you use string as parameter instead of `@<text>`

Comment: But doing that I will lose the strongly-typed advantage of use html helpers inside the parameter.
Anyway, if I use the string, is there a way that I can compile it in my Helper? (Imagine an string formed by the content of my <text> tags example)