# How do I pass multiline HTML as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I need to pass HTML as Parameter to a Html Helper Method (e.g: ClientTemplate in Telerik's Kendo UI MVC Wrapper).

Basicly I try to pass this:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
    <li>Baz</li>
</ul>
```

I tried this:

```
.Template(@<text>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>Foo</li>
        <li>Bar</li>
        <li>Baz</li>
    </ul>
</text>.ToString()))
```

I get this error

`CS1660 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type`

I know it is possible with `"...<li>Foo</li><li>Bar</li>..."` but I am wondering if there is a better method like razors `<text>`

Comment: _"I need to pass HTML as Parameter to a Html Helper Method"_ - why? Anyway why not pass it as a string then (so `"<ul>...</ul>"`)?

Comment: Because I want the benefit of Syntax Highlightning and other Html Helpers in it. @CodeCaster

Comment: Where is quotation marks? .Template(@"<text><ul class='list-unstyled'><li>Foo</li><li>Bar</li><li>Baz</li></ul></text>"))

Comment: Yes, If it is HTML, pass it as string. If you want to maintain razor markup, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157772/asp-net-mvc3-pass-razor-markup-as-a-parameter

Comment: Thank you very much @AshishEmmanuel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Ashish Emmanuel's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34873074/how-do-i-pass-multiline-html-as-parameter#comment57484484_34873074), I have this solution:

**Helper Method**

```
public static string RazorTemplateHelper(Func<object, HelperResult> template)
{
    return template.Invoke(null).ToString();
}
```

**Razor**

```
.Template(RazorTemplateHelper(@<text>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>Foo</li>
        <li>Bar</li>
        <li>Baz</li>
    </ul>
</text>))
```